# Async let - fire-and-forget

Tags: swift, concurrency

I want to fire off multiple calls in parallel but I do not care for their results.
I'd like to use async let syntax for it.

```
func callA() async {
    print("call a")
}

func callB() async {
    print("call b")
}

func callC() async {
    print("call c")
}


func makeCalls() async {
    async let a: Void = callA()
    async let b: Void = callB()
    async let c: Void = callC()
}


func someFuncThatReturnsImmediately() {
    Task {
        await makeCalls()
    }
}
```

This seems to work for this example, but can I be sure that all calls will be made and the task is not cancelled if I don't use await?

Also I get warnings for the unused vars

> Immutable value 'a' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or
> removing it

but if I do replace it that results in an error

> Expression is 'async' but is not marked with 'await'

Is there a way to do this without a warning?

Comment: This is not "fire and forget". You actually await the result, which is Void. "Fire&Forget" would be a synchronous function which starts an async task and immediately returns without returning a side effect caused by the async task.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Same error :/

Comment: @CouchDeveloper wrapped a synchronous function around the task for the example.

Comment: How about just `Task { await callA() }`, `Task { await callB() }` and `Task { await callC() }`?

Comment: "I'd like to use async let syntax for it." Is there a particular reason you don't want to use the correct syntax (what Sweeper writes above)? `async let` is specifically for getting a return value. Are you looking for something clever here to understand `async let` better, or are you actually trying to just run three Tasks (so don't really want `async let`)? Misusing things to understand them better is a fine puzzle, but I want to make sure I know what question you're asking.

Comment: @Sweeper That's how exactly how the example that made me consider this question does it.

Comment: @RobNapier Trying to understand what I can / can't do with async let. But what caused me to look into it was that I didn't like the syntax Sweeper suggested when I saw it in some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async let a: Void = callA()` should work, but you may make some adjustments.

**Fix the warning:**

"Immutable value 'a' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it"

Fix:

```
func makeCalls() async {
    async let _ = callA()
    async let _ = callB()
    async let _ = callC()
}
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by [Robs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76885091/465677), the function `makeCalls()` *as is* does not work yet. The sole definition of the 'async let' constant is not sufficient: you also need to *await* the task, otherwise it will be cancelled before the function returns. Since the task does not return a result, this can be quickly overlooked. Thanks Rob!

```
func makeCalls() async {
    async let a: Void = callA()
    async let b: Void = callB()
    async let c: Void = callC()
    _ = await a
    _ = await b
    _ = await c

}
```

Note also, that in your code *as is*, there is no difference with the code above, since task cancellation is *cooperative* and your tasks do nothing on a cancellation request. So, despite your callA, callB and callC task will be cancelled in the first version of `makeCall()`, they do ignore this cancellation request and run until completion.

**can I be sure that all calls will be made and the task is not cancelled?**

If I understand the question correctly, and if we only examine the function below and do not make any other assumptions:

```
await makeCalls()
```

IFF there is a task where `makeCalls()` has been called, and this task will be cancelled, all your child tasks will be cancelled as well. Note, that in *structured currency*, every task has a parent task, and there will be eventually a root task. In *structured concurrency*, if a task gets cancelled all child tasks get cancelled as well, and hence – iff *structured concurrency* – all their child tasks as well.

However, if you create your own task explicitly (NOT structured concurrency), like here:

```
func someFuncThatReturnsImmediately() {
    Task {
        await makeCalls()
    }
}
```

then, since you have no reference to the task and no code that does cancel the task explicitly, the task will run until completion, i.e. when all child tasks have been finished.

Note though, that your tasks neither return a result nor do they throw an error. The caller has no way to get noticed about cancellation. The only way to perceive somewhere something is by observing the *side effects* of the tasks themselves – for example, they may print out a log statement.

**Alternative**

If you want to run tasks in parallel and as "fire & forget", you may also run them within a *TaskGroup*:

```
func fireAndForgetSomeTasks() {
    Task {
        await withDiscardingTaskGroup { taskGroup in
            taskGroup.addTask { await callA() }
            taskGroup.addTask { await callB() }
            taskGroup.addTask { await callC() }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there are various ways to use a TaskGroup which is very powerful. Please also read the documentation.

Note also, that Task cancellation is *cooperative*. That means, that any task which will be cancelled (better: a request to cancel the task is made) needs to take either proactive measurements or needs to poll the cancellation state in order to handle the cancellation request.

Comment: This was what I was looking for:
"However, if you create your own task explicitly (NOT structured concurrency), like here: then, since you have no reference to the task and no code that does cancel the task explicitly, the task will run until completion, i.e. when all child tasks have been finished."
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's my Xcode version (14.2)... but the async let _ = callA() is giving me the error I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DavidSchmoecker The statement `async let _ = callA() ` should compile without warning or error. However, as mentioned by @Rob in his answer, you have to await the async let constants. A single definition of an 'async let' without awaiting it, will cancel the task.

Comment: @DavidSchmoecker I cannot reproduce the error with Xcode 14.3 and 15.0 beta 6 you mentioned when using `async let _ = callA() `.  Can you please update your question with a code snippet that produces the error "Expression is 'async' but is not marked with 'await'".

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use `async let`, then you must `await`:

```swift
func makeCalls() async {
    async let a: Void = callA()
    async let b: Void = callB()
    async let c: Void = callC()

    _ = await a
    _ = await b
    _ = await c
}
```

Note, if you do not `await` these three `async` calls, when it hits the end of the method, those subtasks will be canceled, and it will subsequently implicitly `await` the canceled subtasks. You might not notice this cancelation with methods with only `print` statements, but do something that supports cancelation (like a network request), and the problem will jump out at you.

For more information, see [Implicit async let awaiting](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md#implicit-async-let-awaiting) section of SE-0317.

Alternatively, one can use a task group:

```swift
func makeCalls() async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask { await self.callA() }
        group.addTask { await self.callB() }
        group.addTask { await self.callC() }
    }
}
```

Comment: `_ = await a` absolutely. It was too easy to overlook. I will make an update in my answer, too. Thanks Rob!

Comment: From the link @Rob posted here: "A async let that was declared but never awaited on explicitly as the scope in which it was declared exits, will be awaited on implicitly. "
That solved the second mystery for me. 
Many thanks!